# Excel: why pasting 9.559E+08 from text file produces 9.56E+11?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I paste from text file this:

```
9.559E+08
```

into Excel.

To my surprise Excel displays it as:

```
9.56E+11
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Why?

UPD: Pasting `9.55E+8` produces [image] (expected). Pasting `9.551E+8` produces [image] (unexpected).

UPD1: Here is a screenshot showing numbers in text file (on the right) and corresponding numbers in Excel after pasting (on the left):

[image]

Comment: do you use commas as decimal points in your locale?

Comment: No. `Decimal symbol` is `.`.

Comment: If you widen the cell, is your `9.55E+8` left justified or right justified? I cannot reproduce your problem with Windows Regional Settings set to United States, where decimal is `.` (dot) and thousands separator is `.` (comma).  What country is your WRS set to?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It is right justified.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The "Country or region" set to "United States".

Comment: you have display precision fixed at 2 decimal places. Increase it or change the number format https://www.lifewire.com/excel-decimal-format-options-3124037 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-a-number-to-the-decimal-places-i-want-49b936f9-6904-425d-aa98-02ffb7f9a17b

Comment: Ensure that under File/Options/Advanced you have checked to `Use System Separators`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ensured.

Comment: Try starting Excel in safe mode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Tried. The problem persists.

Comment: Can you upload the text file causing the problem to some sharing site, and post a link here?

Answer (score 0):

Logic, and experimentation, shows the only way the jump from +8 to +11 happens is if Excel is interpreting the (shown in the pics) `.` as the thousands separator.

If it is, then all the examples make sense in an undamaged installation of Excel. Especially that a "malformed" (in the above case) numeral such as the (seemingly) two decimal place version that gives a "+8" when a similar, but (seemingly) three decimal place version give a "+11".

That is, it is seeing the `9.559+08` as nine thousand, five hundred fifty-nine and converting to a single digit plus decimals hence the +08 becoming the +11.

Why? Those comments certainly cover the usual suspects. Looking at it wrongly, one could say there's something really wrong here. Looking at it the right way, one would say "Well, the facts on the ground are it is doing THIS, so it's up to me to find the reason."

Clearly it will turn out to be a subtlety, but the process is Excel takes your paste, and then decides how to treat the pasted material. Given it is, or at least looks like it to Excel, all numerical value related characters, it tries to interpret it as such. To do so, it tests them against the operating system's settings. Usually we just check the two separators, but EVERY related setting can affect this as, if Excel finds a seemingly direct match, it will ignore the simple separator setting when interpreting the string.

Once it decides it is a number, and maybe importantly here "this kind of number" (whatever that might be in a general sense, but matching a number formatting string in the operating system settings (scientific notation in this case)), it then goes back to itself knowing how it will interpret the value of it for its general work, and looking to its settings, both the general File|Options setting about separators and the particular number formatting string it finds applied to the cell, using its own preferred defaults if "General" is the setting.

At that point, and NOT before, it decides how to USE separators. That is how to use them to display the cell, not how to use them in the earlier steps above.

So if Excel is functioning properly (a defective installation is always a possibility), it MUST... there is no other possiblity... MUST be finding an operating system setting that trumps the operating system's simple separator settings.

Even if something very odd (as in "infrequent") is happening here, like one has some language pack installed and it brought unusual formatting strings, ones not usually encountered, that's still only an effect at the very end when the value which has already been decided upon is displayed. So it would not change value, only display strangely. The pics show a value change. That change happens because Excel decided the value is not what you decided it was, and that decision controlled its introduction into the spreadsheet and now, after it was decided, makes it display oddly. It is that decision about the value of the imported string that is messing things up here.

(In this kind of question, one often interprets the pics wrongly as the poster puts up pics that have the cells right-justified so text looks the same as numbers if all numerals, that kind of unfortunate wackiness, but those do not see values apparently altered and this does. So that kind of thing is not an issue here.)

Carefully examine ALL the number formatting in the operating system's settings. Something there, apparently something subtle, is the culprit.